# Maximum size of size_t

Tags: c, gcc, sizeof, c99, size-t

I know in `C` return type of `sizeof` operator is `size_t` being unsigned integer type defined in `<stdint.h>`. Which means max size of it should be `65535` as stated in `C99` standard [7.18.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.18.3):

```
limit of size_t
  SIZE_MAX             65535
```

However in `gcc-4.8.2` header file `stdint.h` has defined its size much greater than `65535` contradicting to which is stated in `C99` standard as below shown,

```
/* Limit of `size_t' type.  */
# if __WORDSIZE == 64
#  define SIZE_MAX              (18446744073709551615UL)
# else
#  define SIZE_MAX              (4294967295U)
# endif
```

Kindly help me in understanding why there is a difference or reason behind my misinterpretation.

Comment: [How to get SIZE_MAX in C89](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44401965/995714)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The standard says that `SIZE_MAX` must be *at least* 65535.

It specifies no upper bound, and gcc's implementation is perfectly valid.

Quoting the reference you cited (emphasis added):

> Its implementation-defined value shall be **equal to or greater** in magnitude (absolute value) than the corresponding value given below, with the same sign.

Comment: Now it makes sense. `SIZE_MAX  65535` is minimum limit, which I got confused with `limit of size_t` thinking it as maximum limit. Thanks

Comment: @SunEric: Right, `65535` is the minimum maximum.

Comment: Suspect `SIZE_MAX` upper bound is `UINTMAX_MAX`.

Comment: @chux: `SIZE_MAX` can't be bigger than `UINTMAX_MAX`, but there's no specified upper bound on `UINTMAX_MAX`. (It's only slightly less useful to say that the upper bound of `SIZE_MAX` is `SIZE_MAX`.)

Comment: Various limits in C often have a relationship such as `SIZE_MAX <= UINTMAX_MAX`.  (likely all unsigned are so limited - yet many do not know this - hence my comment.)  But some limits are not well ordered like `SIZE_MAX` compared to `LONG_MAX`.  These 2 comes into interaction using `fseek()` (which returns long) to allocate a block to match a file using `malloc()` which takes a `size_t`.